# Are generics specialized during compilation or they are just like java generics only for compile time checks?

Tags: swift, generics

There are three ways to implement generics:

1. Just a tool for compile time checks, but every template instance
   is compiled to the same byte/assembly code implementation (Java, as noted in comments "type erasure" implementation)
2. Each template instantiation is compiled to specialized code (C++, C#)
3. Combination of #1 and #2

Which one is implemented in Swift?

Comment: new technology, first posts, million vote-ups

Comment: For Java generics, the term you're referring to is "type erasure."

Comment: @gaussblurinc Exactly! On a bright side it helps to build knowledge base really fast!

Comment: @Alfa07 and also it dramatically increases your score! :D

Comment: This has *absolutely nothing* to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Swift starts by compiling a single implementation that does dynamic type checking, but the optimizer can then choose to clone off specialized implementations for particular types when the speed vs code size tradeoffs make sense. Ideally, this gets 90% of the speedup of always cloning, without the code size and compilation time exploding.

Comment: please, add examples in your answer :)

Comment: Hm, I don't know how I could. The code would be the same regardless, only the generated binary would change.