# Swift Generics - return equals if they are Equatable, or return nil

Tags: swift, generics

Is there a way to check if a generic type conforms to Equatable or not? I would like to be able to check if two objects of the same generic type are equal or not, or if equality has no meaning for them.

As Equatable can only be used as a generic constraint (because it has Self or associatedType requirements) I have tried using generic overloading:

```
//If T is equatable, this is more specific so should be called
func equals<T:Equatable>(lhs:T, rhs:T) -> Bool?{
    return lhs == rhs
}

//This should only be called if T is not equatable at compile time
func equals<T>(lhs:T, rhs:T) -> Bool?{
    return nil
}
```

This works when called with a specific type, e.g. `equals(lhs:1, rhs:1)` returns `true` as expected. However, if it is called in a generic context it always returns `nil`:

```
func doSomethingThenCheckEquals<T>(lhs:T, rhs:T){
    //Do something here which has no type requirements

    //Check if the two objects are equal - would usually do something with the result
    //This will always use equals<T> and never equals<T:Equatable>, so will always be nil
    _ = equals(lhs:lhs, rhs:rhs) 
}
```

Is there some way to achieve the desired result?

Further, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022608/7028368), the compiler starts with a single implementation with dynamic type checking but can in some cases create specialized implementations. In the case that the compiler created a specialized implementation, would it behave similarly to the first case (where `equals(lhs:1, rhs:1)` returns `true`)?

Comment: Why do you expect ```false``` when calling ```equals(lhs:1, rhs:1)```?

Comment: Ah, good point - I would not

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is doing its job as expected. The second method which you have declared is independent of the first and so it doesn't know anything about `T`.

Generic is forward declaration which means we need to tell the compiler what protocol it will follow and then the compiler will take all necessary step to fit this in. Maybe in future, we can expect function call level type interpretation but currently, it is not available.

```
func doSomethingThenCheckEquals<T>(lhs:T, rhs:T){
//Do something here which has no type requirements

   //Check if the two objects are equal - would usually do something with the result
   //This will always use equals<T> and never equals<T:Equatable>, so will always be nil
    _ = equals(lhs:lhs, rhs:rhs) 
}
```

The best solution would be to use `where` clause.

```
 func doSomethingThenCheckEqual<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) where T:Equatable {


 }
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

Comment: This is not really a solution, as I would like to do something regardless of whether T conforms to Equatable. Your answer would require me to write ```func doSomethingThenCheckEquals<T:Equatable>(lhs:T, rhs:T)``` AND ```func doSomethingThenCheckEquals<T>(lhs:T, rhs:T)``` which do exactly the same thing, except the second doesn't check equals. This is unacceptable as if it is inside another generic function then it won't work for the same reason my 'equals' functions don't work, and it also requires code duplication.